# Delete From MultiPle Table Using Single Query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I know it is a very silly question, and it may be found all over the internet, but still if you all dont mind i want someone to point out the problem in my query. I am using a single query to delete from multiple table, i dnt have any foreign keys in the two tables..

Here's the table structure of the two table

table 1: dt_my_domain

```
|----------|----------------|
| username | domain_email   |
|----------|----------------|
```

and

table 2: dt_my_contact

```
|----------|-------|----------------|------------------|--------|
| user     | email | contact_person | contact_email    |  type  |
|----------|-------|----------------|------------------|--------|
```

now, the table dt_my_domain have username as primary key,
and domain_email is unique.

similarly in table dt_my_contact email is unique.

I want to delete from the two table, on the basis of domain_email and email so that when the two matches the corressponding tuple gets deleted from the two tables

Here's the query i'm running,

```
DELETE FROM dt_my_domain, dt_my_contact
   USING dt_my_domain
INNER JOIN dt_my_contact USING(email) 
WHERE dt_my_domain.domain_email = 'saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com'
```

so, its giving the database error

```
Unknown column 'email' in 'from clause'
```

Now How can i solve this by my query, I want to debug or the problem with this query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE d,c FROM dt_my_domain d inner join dt_my_contact c
   on d.domain_email = c.email
WHERE d.domain_email = 'saswat.saz.routroy@gmail.com'
```

Comment: i want to know why my query isnt running, its not wrong since i have used it earier...

Comment: in my point of view, the syntax is not correct.U manage to run it earlier?

Comment: `USING dt_my_domain
INNER JOIN dt_my_contact USING(email)` i think this part is not correct. `USING (column_list)` instead of `USING (table_name)` in your case.

Comment: yeah, i run it earlier, thats why i used this query, however it was about three table, each of which having user_id as primary key, and the tables were td_user_registration, td_user_general and td_user_professional, where user_id was the primary key in each of the three tables.. my query doesnthave syntactical error, otherwise the error regarding the query wud have been a syntactical one, instead its saying, unknown column field