# single query to delete from multiple tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to delete rows from two tables using single delete query for .net application.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (User_Id, Name, Address, Group);
CREATE TABLE Table2 (User_Id, Role, Application);

INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Mike', 'Michael', 'NJ', 'Dev');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Cla', 'Clark', 'Tampa', 'Supp');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('Ton', 'Tony', 'Tulsa', 'Tes');

INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('Ton', 'AM', 'Science');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('Cla', 'SM', 'Magazine');
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES ('Mike','M', 'Sports');

DELETE Table1, Table2
FROM   Table1
JOIN   Table2 ON (Table2.User_Id = Table1.User_Id)
WHERE  Table1.User_Id = '';
```

Pls advice whether it is a good practice or is it better to go for SP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825648/delete-from-multiple-table-using-single-query-in-mysql

Please see above post, it will answer your query.

Comment: The link goes to a question tagged `mysql`. Does this work on SQL Server too?

Comment: Delete T1, T2 from Table1 T1 inner join Table 2 T2 ON T1.User_Id = T2.User_Id where T1.User_Id = //what should I put here since I am gonna use this for asp.net application. Certainly I can put values if I am gonna run it from SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

this is only possible if you have a foreign key constraint between your tables and activate the "cascade delete" option on the constraint.

if you don't want a constraint (although I think it would be a good idea anyway) you could use a trigger to delete corresponding records in child tables

Comment: +1 good answer... if you don't want to / or can't change the data structure or add a trigger you can always do the two delete statements in a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't possible directly. Of course we can. Lets do it another way

1. Create **ForeignKey with cascade delete enabled option**
2. *Creating delete trigger* on Table1

But in the case of performance i cant prefer u trigger. So enabling cascading Delete should be good.

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_Table1_User_ID
FOREIGN KEY (User_ID)
REFERENCES  Table1(User_ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Cheers,
Sarath